# shaderProgram in cocos2d 3.0 doesn't work

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I have just started with Cocos2d 3.0 after using 1.1 for a long time.
I wanted to test the shaders out and looked up some tutorials.
All tutorials seems to use the CCSprite property "shaderProgram".
When I try it like this:

```
renderTexture.sprite.shaderProgram = [[CCGLProgram alloc] initWithVertexShaderByteArray:ccPositionTextureA8Color_vert fragmentShaderByteArray:ccPositionTextureColorAlphaTest_frag]
```

Xcode gives me an error saying: "Property 'shaderProgram' not found on object type CCSprite *"

Is this property removed or changed from version 2.0 to 3.0 and how would I go about using it in Cocos2d 3.0?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Adding this import:

```
#import "CCNode_Private.h"
```

allows you to access CCNode's `shaderProgram` memberc

Comment: File CCNode_Private.h doesn't contain shaderProgram member